# scrapy crawl same url over and over

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy function that loops recursively through a URL, on every iteration I get a JSON response that contains the HTML page and a number that I use as a parameter to call the same URL to get the new data and so on...

The problem is that in the second iteration I don't get the response object updated (the next iteration will contain the old response from the first iteration), and thus the same url gets scraped over and over.

Is there a way to tell scrapy not to process until it gets the new response? something like a synchronous call, since every iteration will depend on the parameter received by the old iteration.

my code looks like the following:

```
def parse_tweets(self, response):
    while(self.keepScroll):
        #convert response
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        selector = Selector(text=data['items_html'], type='html')
        #extract next position parameter
        nextPosition = data['min_position'].split('-')
        nextPosition = 'TWEET-'+nextPosition[1] + '-' + nextPosition[2]
        #extract data
        comments_react = self.stats_extractor('reply', selector)
        retweet_react = self.stats_extractor('retweet', selector)
        favorite_react = self.stats_extractor('favorite', selector)
        tweets = selector.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"js-stream-item stream-item stream-item")]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/p/text()').extract()
        tweetdates = selector.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"js-stream-item stream-item stream-item")]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/small/a/span[1]/text()').extract()

        yield {
         'comments' : comments_react,
         'retweets' : retweet_react,
         'favorites' : favorite_react,
         'teweets' : tweets,
         'tweetDates' : tweetdates,
        }
        #update parameter to get next data
        self.get_params['max_position'] = nextPosition
        self.keepScroll = data['has_more_items']
        #call the new API with the nex parameters
        yield Request(self.tweetAPIGetParams[0]+'?'+urlencode(self.get_params), callback=self.parse_tweets,dont_filter=True,cookies=self.API_Cookies,headers=self.params)
```

Comment: is the response updated by the request yielded in the last line of you `while`? if so, you should only remove the while

Comment: thanks that worked fine, i get what i did wrong, i feel so stupid.